# Print listview with paging

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a listview that contains more than 300 record,I want to print this listview but every 50 record in a page. How can I perform this task in ASP.net

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq to get only the record you need

```
MyList.Skip(pageNo * totalPerPage).Take(totalPerPage).ToList()
```

Comment: Create a method that accept pageno and records per page so with a simply Linq you can return only the row that you need for further processing